# Supplier <Stream> yields empty stream, but as a list, it's not empty

Tags: java-8, java-stream

In my code, I have to iterate through a bunch of objectsof type `T` more than once. Since some objects may be quite large, I resorted to using a `Supplier` of `Stream<T>` instead of collecting them all in a list or set. The method is as follows:

```
private static Supplier<Stream<T>> streamSupplier(...) {
    Iterator<T> iterator = ...;
    Iterable<T> iterable = () -> iterator;
    return () -> StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
}
```

and elsewhere in the code

```
Supplier<Stream<T>> supplier = streamSupplier(...);
List<T> ts = supplier.get().collect(Collectors.toList());
return ts.isEmpty(); // <-- true
```

The problem is that when I call the `Supplier#get()` method on the supplier returned by the above method, it is **always** empty. But when I changed my code to return a list, everything is working fine:

```
private static List<T> listSupplier(...) {
    Iterator<T> iterator = ...;
    Iterable<T> iterable = () -> iterator;
    List<T> ts = Lists.newArrayList(iterable);
    return ts; // <-- is populated correctly, NOT empty
}
```

I thought using a `Supplier` is the correct way to go if I want to use a stream repeatedly (so that I don't end up with a closed `Stream). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the `iterator` implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
private static Supplier<Stream<T>> streamSupplier(...) {
    return () -> {
        Iterator<T> iterator = ...;
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false);
    };
}
```

This assumes that the line

```
Iterator<T> iterator = ...;
```

creates a fresh iterator each time, independently of any existing iterator.

Also note that you should adjust the way the Spliterator is created, for example, if the size is known, or if there are characteristics such as ordering that are important.

Finally, be very careful with doing

```
Iterable<T> iterable = () -> iterator;
```

This is close to being an anti-pattern. While it works in the type system -- calling the resulting Iterable's iterator() method will return an instance of Iterator -- it often won't work. The reason is that most code that uses Iterable instances assumes that it can call iterator() multiple times and get independent iterators. This doesn't do that; it captures the Iterator and returns the *same* Iterator instance each time. This will cause weird breakage similar to what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to create many streams from the same iterator.

Try this:

```
Iterable<Document> docIterable = () -> ...;
```

Where the `...` is from `Iterator<Document> docIterator = ...;`

Also, why are you returning a `Supplier<Stream<Document>>` instead of just `Stream<Document>`?

Comment: I, too, thought this was the reason. But then, at least the very first call should return a non-empty stream, right?

Also, returning the supplier is equivalent to returning the stream in my case, is it not? All I am doing is calling `get()` on the supplier instead of calling the method that actually iterates through the documents.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You are trying to get an unnecessarily brittle design to work and it's hard to tell where the problem is without seeing the rest of the code.